# How to demonstrate that Fierz-like identity for 2-components Weyl spinors?

Tags: vectors, spinors, linear-algebra, clifford-algebra, matrix-elements

Consider the 2-components Weyl spinors with the following scalar product
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\langle \, \phi, \, \psi \, \rangle = \phi^{\top} \, \sigma_y \: \phi,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_y$ is the second Pauli matrix.  To each spinor, we could associate a *light-like* four-vector of components
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
n_\psi^a = \psi^{\dagger} \sigma^a \, \psi = \psi_i^{*} \, \sigma_{ij}^a \, \psi_j,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma^0 = 1$, $\sigma^1 = \sigma_x$, $\sigma^2 = \sigma_y$ and $\sigma^3 = \sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices.

Now, using explicit components $\phi = (a, \, b)$ and $\psi = (c, \, d)$ (where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are complex numbers), it is possible to prove the following formula by brute force (it's not too painfull, just a bit long to do):
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
|\langle \, \phi, \, \psi \, \rangle |^2 = \frac{1}{2} \: \eta_{ab} \, n_\phi^a \, n_\psi^b,
\end{equation}
where $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$ is the Minkowski metric of flat spacetime.

I'm wondering if there's a simpler proof of (3), using only properties of the Pauli matrices.  Maybe there's another identity related to $\eta_{ab} \, \sigma_{ij}^a \, \sigma_{pq}^b$?